# How to reduce Font size?

Tags: blackberry

```
public class TestEye extends MainScreen  {

     LabelField l1,l2;
     RichTextField rch;
     VerticalFieldManager vfm; 
     Font myfont1;
     String word[]={"F D","N P","U H","F Z","K R","U V","Z E","E K","P Z","V N"};

 public TestEye()
 {  
         vfm=new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH|VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT)
           {
             protected void paint(Graphics graphics) 
                         {
                           graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                           graphics.fillRect(0, 0, Display.getHorizontalResolution(), Display.getVerticalResolution());
                           super.paint(graphics);
                         }
           };
         l1=new LabelField("----------------",Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH|Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT);
         l2=new LabelField("----------------",Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH|Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT);
         rch=new RichTextField() 
           {


               public void paint(Graphics g)
                { 
                      g.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                      g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                          super.paint(g);
                 }
           }; 
         vfm.add(l1);
         vfm.add(l2);
         vfm.add(rch);
         add(vfm);
         System.out.println("::::::::::::::::end test eye:::::::::::::::");
         push(word);  
  }

  public  void push( final String  arr1[]) {

      new Thread(new Runnable()
       {
          public void run()
            {   
                       int k=20;
                     for( int i=0;i<10;i++)
                       {  
                            try
                               {    
                                  String  data=arr1[i]; 
                                  Font myfont1=Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN,k);
                                  rch.setFont(myfont1);
                                  rch.setText("                     "+(data));
                                  k=k-2;
                                }
                            catch(Exception ex)
                               {
                                  ex.printStackTrace();
                               }
                            try 
                               {
                                  Thread.sleep(2000);
                               }
                            catch (InterruptedException e) 
                               {
                                  e.printStackTrace();
                               }
                         }


              }

        }).start();
  }
}
```

i have to reduce Font size for each word used in String array.
this is my code but here inside for loop Font is not working so please check it and give me some suggestion                                                           thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can try ActiveRichTextField. in ActiveRichTextField not only you can give different fonts, you can give different colors also.

e.g.

```
String data = "Hello World!";
 int offsets[] ={0,5,data.length()};
 Font[] fonts = new Font[] { Font.getDefault(), Font.getDefault()};
 int bg[] = new int[] { Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE};
 int fg[] = new int[] { Color.BLACK, Color.RED};
 byte attributes[] = {0,1};

 add(new ActiveRichTextField(data, offsets, attributes, fonts,
                                fg, bg, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the font for the entire field in your loop. If you want different portions of the field contents to be in different fonts, that's not the way to do it. Take a look at the docs for [`RichTextField`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/RichTextField.html) for how to use the multi-argument `setText` methods to define different fonts for different parts of the text.